# Multiple JSON Schema validators per collection MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, I can set up a JSON Schema validation in a collection I create, such as these:

```
db.createCollection("teste", {
    validator: {
        jsonSchema: {
            bsonType: "object",
            required: ["campo1", "numero1"],
            properties: {
                campo1: {
                    bsonType: "string",
                    description: "Deve ser uma string"
                },
                numero1: {
                    bsonType: "string",
                    description: "Deve ser um texto"
                },
            }
        }
    }
})
```

But I have mixed-type collections that make use of the [Polymorphic Pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-polymorphic-pattern). Where I have something like five or more "types" of schema that are accepted in a collection.

Can I setup multiple JSON Schema validators in a collection? or just one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. $jsonSchema is just another query operator, you can use $or and $and the same way as you would in the filter:

```
{
  $or: [
    {
      $jsonSchema: {
        ...
      }
    },
    {
      $jsonSchema: {
        ...
      }
    }
  ]
}
```